# Including Lucene nightly jar in Play 2 SBT project

Tags: playframework, sbt

I'm using the Play 2 Framework, which uses SBT, and am trying to include the Lucene nightly jar in my project.  I've added the following to my plugins.sbt:

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
    DefaultMavenRepository,
    Resolver.url("Play", url("http://download.playframework.org/ivy-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
    "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
    "Lucence Snapshot Repository" at "https://builds.apache.org/job/Lucene-Solr-Maven-trunk/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/maven_artifacts/"
)
```

However, it cannot find the jar.  It doesn't appear to even be checking the new repository:

```
[warn]  module not found: org.apache.lucene#lucene-analyzers-common;4.0-SNAPSHOT       
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /usr/local/users/bmccann/Play20/framework/../repository/local/org.apache.lucene/lucene-    analyzers-common/4.0-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/apache/lucene/lucene-analyzers-common/4.0-SNAPSHOT/lucene-analyzers-common-4.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Snapshots Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/org/apache/lucene/lucene-analyzers-common/4.0-SNAPSHOT/lucene-analyzers-common-4.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/lucene/lucene-analyzers-common/4.0-SNAPSHOT/lucene-analyzers-common-4.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository: tried
[warn]   http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/org/apache/lucene/lucene-analyzers-common/4.0-SNAPSHOT/lucene-analyzers-common-4.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                           
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.apache.lucene#lucene-analyzers-common;4.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Does SBT do some caching of these repos that I need to reset?  Can it not handle an https repo?  I can't figure out what's going on here.  Is anyone else able to include the jar into their project?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the URL

https://builds.apache.org/job/Lucene-Solr-Maven-trunk/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/maven_artifacts/

is the correct URL for the Maven repository? When I open it in a browser I see a Jenkins instance, it doesn't look right to me...

Checking around, I could only find repos for the stable versions, so I have the feeling you need to manually download the nightly build one if you want it. I may have missed the proper repository, though.

Comment: They are built by Jenkins, but I'm pretty sure it's still a Maven repository.  It's in a directory structure that matches what is required by Maven, the POM files are there, etc.  You can host a Maven repo in just about any form as long as the requirements are met.  I've seen them as jars checked in to somone's googlecode or GitHub in that structure, for example.  Here are a couple docs that refer to that nightly as being a valid Maven repo:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/dev-tools/maven/README.maven
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/NightlyBuilds

Answer (score 0):

I manage to add the lucene dependency by adding this to the Build.scala file:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
....
 "org.apache.lucene" % "lucene-core" % "3.0.0"
)
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: Thanks.  I was trying to figure it out for Lucene 4 though =)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [readme](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/dev-tools/maven/README.maven) you posted. This worked for me:

```
resolvers += "Apache Snapshots" at "http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.lucene" % "lucene-analyzers-common" % "4.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

Here's the output

```
> compile
[info] Updating {file:/Users/eed3si9n/work/helloworld/}app...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] downloading http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/org/apache/lucene/lucene-analyzers-common/4.0-SNAPSHOT/lucene-analyzers-common-4.0-20120918.141722-107.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.lucene#lucene-analyzers-common;4.0-SNAPSHOT!lucene-analyzers-common.jar (3647ms)
[info] downloading http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/org/apache/lucene/lucene-core/4.0-SNAPSHOT/lucene-core-4.0-20120918.141624-107.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.lucene#lucene-core;4.0-SNAPSHOT!lucene-core.jar (4295ms)
[info] Done updating.
```